# How to force a type to be defined by the given argument

Tags: typescript

**Background situation:**

```
// Type to do the validation - not so important.
type Validate<N, S> = [S] extends [N] ? N : never;

// Note that with below line, N will have a circular constraint when using from validateName().
// type Validate<N, S> = S extends N ? N : never;

// The function to validate - how it runs as JS (or even what it returns) is not important.
// .. However, it is important that it must use a Validate type with two arguments like above.
function validateName<N extends string, S extends Validate<N, S>>(input: S) {}
```

**Problem**:
How to supplement only `N` but not `S` to the `validateName` (or `Validate`) above? We want `S` to remain inferred by the actual argument.

```
// Test.
type ValidNames = "bold" | "italic";

// Desired usage:
// .. But we can't do this due to "Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1."
validateName<ValidNames>("bold");   // Ok.
validateName<ValidNames>("bald");   // Error.

// Cannot solve like below due to: "Type parameter defaults can only reference previously declared type parameters."
function validateName<N extends string, S extends Validate<N, S> = Validate<N, S>>(input: S) {}
```

**Working workarounds:**

Workaround #1: Store the input as a variable, and use its type.

```
const input1 = "bold";
const input2 = "bald";
validateName<ValidNames, typeof input1>(input1);  // Ok.
validateName<ValidNames, typeof input2>(input2);  // Error.
```

Workaround #2: Make the function require extra argument.

```
function validateNameWith<N extends string, S extends Validate<N, S>>(_valid: N, input: S) {}
validateNameWith("" as ValidNames, "bold");  // Ok.
validateNameWith("" as ValidNames, "bald");  // Error.
```

Workaround #3: Use closure - by wrapping the function inside another.

```
// First a function to create a validator and put N into it.
function createValidator<N extends string>() {
    // Return the actual validator.
    return function validateName<S extends Validate<N, S>>(input: S) {}
}
const validateMyName = createValidator<ValidNames>();
validateMyName("bold");  // Ok.
validateMyName("bald");  // Error.
```

---

**Edited:** Modified the functions above by removing the confusing `:N[]` return part.

**More info / the context**:

I'm actually trying to build a string validator that can be used, eg. for html class names. Everything else works, except the usage is clunky (see the 3 workarounds above).

```
// Thanks to: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
    [S];

// Type to validate a class name.
type ClassNameValidator<N extends string, S extends string, R = string> =
    Split<S, " "> extends N[] ? R : never;

// Function to validate class.
function validateClass<N extends string, S extends ClassNameValidator<N, S>>(input: S) {}

const test3 = "bold italic";
const test4 = "bald";
validateClass<ValidNames, typeof test3>(test3);  // Ok.
validateClass<ValidNames, typeof test4>(test4);  // Error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I accidentally found a solution (or a clean workaround). It's the same background idea as in workaround #3, but implemented purely in TS (no extra JS). The idea is to separate the `N` and `S` parts using a "type closure": namely, to define a function with a generic `N` param on the left hand side, and use the `S` only on the right hand side.

```
// Create a type for validation function, separating N and S.
// .. Using the ClassNameValidator from the original question.
type Validate<N extends string> = <S extends ClassNameValidator<N, S>>(input: S) => void;

// Then we can supplement just N - without S.
// .. Note that the actual js function can be reused (eg. from a library).
const validateClass: Validate<ValidNames> = (_input) => {}

// Test.
validateClass("bold");  // Ok.
validateClass("italic bold");  // Ok.
validateClass("bald");  // Error.
```

Note that this solves the problem for me - though it's not strictly what was asked in the title (which seems to be currently impossible).

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution that works for you. Instead of having a `Validation` type, you could have a type that calculates all permutations of the possible values based on the given `string` union.

```
type AllPermutations<T extends string> = {
  [K in T]: 
    | `${K}${AllPermutations<Exclude<T, K>> extends infer U extends string 
        ? [U] extends [never] 
          ? "" 
          : ` ${U}` 
        : ""}` 
    | `${AllPermutations<Exclude<T, K>> extends infer U extends string 
        ? U 
        : never}`
}[T]

// Function to validate class.
function validateClass<N extends string>(input: AllPermutations<N>) {}
```

It passes the following tests.

```
type ValidNames = "bold" | "italic";

validateClass<ValidNames>("bold");  // Ok.
validateClass<ValidNames>("bold italic");  // Ok.
validateClass<ValidNames>("italic");  // Ok.
validateClass<ValidNames>("italic bold");  // Ok.
validateClass<ValidNames>("something else");  // Error.
```

But if the union gets bigger, this will become perfomance hungry. I would not advise to use this if `ValidNames` is a larger union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDD0oAgMQVwOwMYBcCWB7OElogNwIYA2KAJvkgKYQKH4DOdAdMAGbzLqYHFmUDCtBgB4AchAoAPSnBJ0IdJACcUcAOYA+ABQqADjCQAuCAEFChAAoVFAW33lOdUeoCUEAN4BfEAgwKsFBQBmCABeCAAiACM0QhIIFCQiFARwgG5gHzg-SgUAFlCIyKISNJAkAE8dKlMLK1tE1F8hABVxKQoZOQVlNXUCt2AICABtAGl4zGaAXSNBoYgAHwgAAwASN1GPdZrLGztGrKEAUQkaGBIKFoAaCFH1PslpWQmWKwgAVTanrqUVVQg5vN5gB+EbvKZfDrPYZwCi4KwQwFAkERcIA5HIozLCDrd4ebFIoFGcLhfHo+ZLNZuHZ1fYOY6nQjnS7NG53B7tTovN6fR5Qn49f6ElGfYVDIyw+GKfHADzDaZlSpUABqSRIInw1gCBSiMRKiwiCSSKXSwG4pHIFAE9Ecqp4Gq1dC0uti4WcqSG4AgAHkANbMc28K2CW1qh0BZ3RWLxRLEFLuz2QP0BtWW63CO2kcNOzThI1xt0eiBe5Nm1P8ENCTPqzUR3P55IQKMlBPFpP+ss8NOV6vZ510NBapAACz+4kIdAohcTECOikUaEUjCAA)

Comment: No it doesn't solve it. I need to use that `S` to do validation in the form of `Validate<N, S>` . I didn't want to complicate the example / situation any further, but maybe will add more background info.  (I'm actually using it to split a string in TS, eg. "bold italic", and I have a type to do that - but it's not related to the problem at hand.)

Comment: @takaturre please edit your question to include your real example. Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: I edited to provide a step bigger context. However, it does not change the core question / issue - though, of course, helps to understand and maybe someone might even come up with out-of-box alternatives.

Comment: Okay, this is much better, thanks! However I want to clarify one thing (as I'm just learning TS): Does this actually create all those valid strings, like "bold italic" and "italic bold", or just create a sort of "dynamic" type to match against? Because I considered this approach initially and came to the conclusion that this would soon get very heavy. For example consider having, say, 100 class names, then to create all those permutations....

Comment: It would generate them all when using the function. You would probably get an error if `ValidNames` is that large. I just tested it and the editor becomes unresponsive at around 10 elements.

Comment: Okay, so it's the pre-heavy-way unfortunately. In this case, I'd prefer one of my workarounds (#2 and #3). Anyway, super useful for learning TS, thanks a lot!

Comment: This will probably be possible some day, when TypeScript gets partial type inference. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242